# Help writing a query to transform rows with json data into 1 download file

Tags: postgresql

I want to write a query for a table like this:

```
id  job_id  data (bytea)
--------------------------
 1       1  {"hello": "John"}
 2       1  {"goodbye": "Moon"}
 ...
100      2  {"also": "Hi"}
```

I want to be able to ask:

```
> Give me all the data for job #1
```

and have the text file automatically built like this:

```
{"hello": "John"}
{"goodbye": "Moon"}
```

My concern is if the bytea size is too large, I need to get one-row at a time, and extract the data from it. This seems to work:

```
    select encode(data, 'escape') from mytable where id='1'
```

But I would rather not do 2 queries (one to get all rows - and another to get data). Can I issue a single query, and somehow paginate, one row at a time? Number of rows can be large, e.g. 100k.

Any tips to point me in the right direction are much appreciated.

P.S.: Order is not that important to me. E.g. this is ok too (if this helps):

```
{"goodbye": "Moon"}
{"hello": "John"}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1517692/3270427

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't store JSON as bytea. Store it as [`jsonb` or `json`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html).

Maybe I don't understand your question

```
ALTER TABLE table
  ALTER COLUMN data
  SET DATA TYPE jsonb USING encode(data, 'escape')::jsonb;
```

Then just do.. `SELECT * FROM table WHERE job_id = 1`

> My concern is if the bytea size is too large, I need to get one-row at a time, and extract the data from it.

Why? What does *too large* mean there? The way this works, you'll only `encode` one row at a time and send it to the client...

Comment: Thanks. This works, but I realize now my question was phrased imprecisely. I actually meant that my `data` field can be binary of any sort, including pdfs, images or other documents. I can see how with json this is the best option. For now - this is all I need anyways. Thank you.